# How to make a list a certain size (k)

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension

I am creating a function that finds a k-nearest neighbors prediction.

```
def knn_predict(data, x_new, k):
    """ (tuple, number, int) -> number

    data is a tuple.
    
    data[0] are the x coordinates and 
    data[1] are the y coordinates.
    
    k is a positive nearest neighbor parameter.
    
    Returns k-nearest neighbor estimate using nearest
    neighbor parameter k at x_new.
    
    Assumes i) there are no duplicated values in data[0],
    ii) data[0] is sorted in ascending order, and
    iii) x_new falls between min(x) and max(x).
    
    >>> knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 2, 2)
    4.0
    
    >>> knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 2, 3)
    1.0

    >>> knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 8, 2)
    1.0

    >>> knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 8, 3)
    4.333333333333333
    """
    
  
    #use find_index and the x_new value for k loops to find N\/k(x_new) (list of indexes)
    #incorporate k value!!!
    nk = [find_index(data[0], x_new) for k in range(k)] #here
    #use N\/k(x_new) indexes to find correlated y values
    yvals = [data[1][val] for val in nk]
    #use correlated y values summed together divided by k to find y new
    ynew = sum(yvals) / k
    return ynew
```

important line:

```
nk = [find_index(data[0], x_new) for k in range(k)] #here
```

The line with #here at the end is supposed to use this function:

```
def find_index(x, x_new):
    """ (list, number) -> int
    
    Returns the smallest index i such that x[i] <= x_new 
    and x[i+1] >= x_new.
    
    Assumes i) there are no duplicated values in x,
    ii) x is sorted in ascending order, and
    iii) x_new falls between min(x) and max(x).
    
    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 1)
    0

    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 2)
    0

    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 6)
    1

    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 7)
    1

    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 8)
    2

    >>> find_index([1, 5, 7, 9], 9)
    2
    """
   
    for i, element in enumerate(x):
        
        if x_new <= x[i+1] and element <= x_new:
            return i
```

and return the indexes. k is the number of indexes it will find. How can I correctly fix the line so that it finds k number of index (the list should be k long)

Comment: Are you sure about this?  `find_index` does not find the NEAREST neighbor, it just finds the interval.  Look at your example with 7.  Clearly, index 2 is the nearest neighbor not index 1.

Comment: i use find_index to find the interval at which the y values (that I sum in the ynew equation) will correspond to @TimRoberts

Comment: But that's not correct.  Consider `find_index([1,9,11,13], 8)`.  That's going to return 0, when in fact ALL of the other elements of the list are closer than index 0.  I suppose that given the interval, you could search left and right to find nearest, but that seems silly.

Comment: I guess I am just confused, but thank you for your help I will use your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves your problem in three lines of code.  I don't think `find_index` is useful at all.  Notice that this code doesn't care if the entries are in order or not, or even whether the value is between min(x) and max(x).

```
def knn_predict(data, x_new, k):
    """ (tuple, number, int) -> number

    data is a tuple.
    
    data[0] are the x coordinates and 
    data[1] are the y coordinates.
    
    k is a positive nearest neighbor parameter.
    
    Returns k-nearest neighbor estimate using nearest
    neighbor parameter k at x_new.
    """
    
    # Find the deltas from our target to the x values.
    
    deltas = [(abs(t-x_new),y) for t,y in zip(*data)]

    # Sort the values by the distance.

    deltas.sort()

    # Return the sum of the Ys.

    return sum( d[1] for d in deltas[:k] ) / k

print( knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 2, 2) )
print( knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 2, 3) )
print( knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 8, 2) )
print( knn_predict(([0, 5, 10, 15], [1, 7, -5, 11]), 8, 3) )
```

Output:

```
4.0
1.0
1.0
4.333333333333333
```

Comment: this is smart, but I need to use find_index for the assignment

Comment: That doesn't make sense, because it doesn't solve the problem you have specified.

Comment: it doesn't solve the problem, but it helps me find the one part that I then use to solve the problem

Comment: No, actually, it doesn't.  See the example I cited above.  It gives you information, but it's not useful information.